# How to register a Filter to one @RequestMapping method only?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I registered the following filter for general content logging:

```
@Bean
public Filter getLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    filter.setMaxPayloadLength(5120);
    return filter;
}
```

This filter catches on any request.

Now I'd like to apply this filter to only one specific `@RequestMapping` method.

Question: is that possible at all?

**Update**: the following filterbean results in a 404 when accessing the path.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean getLoggingFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter());
    filter.addUrlPatterns("/rest/my/specific/method/*");
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: No. You could add the URL pattern but that is it. Filters operate on a plain request/response and don't know anything about what lurks behind that.

Comment: How can I add the URL pattern? I could not find any methon in the filter like `setPath` or similar. It would be sufficient if I could define the target path like `/rest/my/specific/method/*`

Comment: You cannot do that on the filter... Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes I'm using spring-boot.

Comment: Add a [`FilterRegistrationBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean.html) to set the URL patterns. As explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans).

Comment: If I apply a `FilterRegistrationBean` as above I'm suddenly getting a `404` on the path (which worked if I just the the `Filter` bean above). See my update please.

Comment: You should have both a filter and filter registration.

Comment: Hm, I tried adding both Filter and the FilterRegistrationBean, and configured with `filter.addUrlPatterns("*");`. Now the path works, but the filter is not executed.

Comment: * isn't a valid path.

Comment: `/*` doesn't work either, neither does `/rest/*`.

Comment: Then you are doing weird things in your application... It should just work, used this on many occasions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a [`FilterRegistrationBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean.html) to specify URLs mappings. This fact is also mentioned in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans).

```
@Bean
public Filter loggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    filter.setMaxPayloadLength(5120);
    return filter;
}
```

Next to the filter definition add the `FilterRegistrationBean`.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean loggingFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(loggingFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/rest/my/specific/method/*");
    return registration;
}
```

This will attach the filter to the specified URL. Also be aware that the `UrlPatterns` are patterns inside the root URL. So if your application is mapped on `/rest` this filter won't be invoked.

Comment: See my final note!. Your application isn't deployed on `/rest` now is it?

Comment: I found the solution: I created my custom filter class, and registered a wrong logger as follows: `private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.class);`. This should instead be `MyCustomLoggingFilter.class`, and then it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One question, as I came back to this today: is it mandatory to create a `@Bean Filter` of `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` if it is anyway only used in the `FilterRegistrationBean`? Shouldn't it be better just a private method?

Comment: calling loggingFilter() explicitely doesnt create a spring bean, does it?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni yes it does as that method is annotated with `@Bean`.

Comment: it does but injecting it this was is wrong - new FilterRegistrationBean(loggingFilter())

Comment: No it isn’t. The method is proxied by spring and you will get the bean instance.

Answer (score 6):

I have got into the same situation recently and I had taken different approach compared with @M.Deinum answer. **`org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`** filter is the derived class of **`org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`** which provides a feature to **`exclude/include`** any endpoints through the method **`OncePerRequestFilter#shouldNotFilter`**. The default return value of this method decides whether the URL has to be filtered or not, as a default return value is **`false`**,  this filter catches on **`any request`**. Luckily, we can customize this behavior by extending the **`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`** class and overriding **`shouldNotFilter`** method. As each `@RequestMapping` annotation is mapped to a endpoint, we can add some custom logic to decide whether the requested URL has to be `chained` to **`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`** or not.

Create a custom class and extend **`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`** and override method  **`shouldNotFilter`**

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CustomCommonsRequestLoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {

    private static final Pattern ONLY_LOGGING_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("/required-url");



    //The default implementation always returns false.
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //It can be either RequestURI(includes context path) 
        String loggingPattern = request.getRequestURI();
        //or ServletPath based on your requirement
        //loggingPattern = request.getServletPath();
         

        // If you want to log a particular endpoint then return false
        // or if you don't want to log the endpoint then return true
        return ONLY_LOGGING_PATTERN.matcher(loggingPattern).find() ? false : true;
    }
}
```

and inject **`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`**  bean as below

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter() {
    CustomCommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CustomCommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    filter.setMaxPayloadLength(5120);
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: Prasanth you should fix the comments in `shouldNotFilterMethod`.
You should say: If you want to log a particular endpoint, return FALSE (not true). And if you want to exclude a particular endpoint, return TRUE (NOT FALSE).  

In other words `shouldNotFilter` returns `true` in order to 'NOT FILTER' and `false` otherwise.

Working for me!

Comment: @PhilippeSimo, Good observation, thanks for the comment, updated the answer