# How to add a filter on all @RequestMapping methods of a Spring servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can I add a filter for any `@RequestMapping` method in any `@RestController`?

I want that filter to apply on the mapping object. Thus, *after* the request has been mapped to the DTO, but *before* the `@RequestMapping` method executes.

Is that possible at all?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public void get(GetDTO dto) {
    } 

    @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public void get(PostDTO dto) {
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198604/how-to-register-a-filter-to-one-requestmapping-method-only

Comment: No. My question is how to add a filter that intercepts between the mapping to dto and calling the `@RequestMapping` mapping. Your linked question is about how to add a filter to a **specific** `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: You can use `HandlerInterceptor`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [interceptors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-):

```
public interface HandlerInterceptor {

    boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response,
                      Object handler) throws Exception
}
```

From javadocs:

> Intercept the execution of a handler. Called after HandlerMapping
>   determined an appropriate handler object, but before HandlerAdapter invokes the handler.

See also [In a Spring-mvc interceptor, how can I access to the handler controller method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575623/in-a-spring-mvc-interceptor-how-can-i-access-to-the-handler-controller-method)

Comment: Though I'm not having the mapped DTO inside that handler, only the raw requests. Image i'd have a servlet that takes POST data in `json` and `xml` format. That would not be nice extracting from `HttpServletRequest` before they are mapping to DTO by spring.

Comment: Can you tell us what are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe there is another way to resolve problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use [aspects](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop), setting a point cut before calling the method you want to intercept.

Something like:

```
@Before("execution(* ..MyServlet.*(*)) && args(param)")
public void beforeGetDTOMethod(GetDTO param) {
    // Advice implementation
}
```

That will intercept calls to any method within MyServlet class with a `GetDTO` parameter.

If what you are trying to achieve is update the input parameter you need to go for an [around](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) advice.

Bear in mind that, when working with aspects, you are working with proxies.

[Before advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema-advice-before)

[Passing parameters to advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing)

[The AspectJ documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/index.html)